# Reading Amazon cloud config's service sections

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, web-config

My requirement is to keep my AWS related config in its own file (like Web.AWS.Config), my application is a .NET 4.6 Web App, and I've made it working as following. I followed the documentation below.Any help much appreciated ! Thanks in advance.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Amazon/TAWSConfigs.html

```xml
<configSections>
   <section name="aws" type="Amazon.AWSSection, AWSSDK.Core"/>
</configSections>

<aws configSource="Web.AWS.config"></aws>
```

In my Web.AWS.config file, I've the following

```xml
<aws profileName="dev" profilesLocation="C:\temp\awscredentials\credentials-file">
    <IdentityPoolId>eu-west-1:62484b27-39ce-4db8-8bcb</IdentityPoolId>
</aws>
```

The AWS SDK is able to read the 'profileName' and the 'profilesLocation' correctly, but cannot read my custom value for 'IdentityPoolId'. Below code can read the aws related config from my seperate Web.AWS.Config file without any issues.

```cs
            CredentialProfile basicProfile;
            AWSCredentials awsCredentials;
            var sharedFile = new SharedCredentialsFile();

            if (sharedFile.TryGetProfile("dev", out basicProfile) && AWSCredentialsFactory.TryGetAWSCredentials(basicProfile, sharedFile, out awsCredentials))
            {
                if (awsCredentials != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        AmazonCognitoIdentityClient cognitoIdentityClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(awsCredentials, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);

                        //more code here ----
                    }
                    catch(Exception xxx)
                    {
                        //handle error
                    }
                }
            }
```

Infact the  tag is entirely made up to accommodate a way to include my pool id. I could see the custom value when I put the mouse over as below under 'servicesections'. But don't see an easy way to read it.

[image]

Any help much appreciated. I want to read the values inside 'ServiceSections' without too much complicated workarounds if possible.